# Why was it Abagus who prophesied about Paul's arrest in Acts 21:11?

Tags: acts, prophecy, paul

We are told that Paul stayed with Philip the evangelist who had four unmarried daughters who prophesied.

Acts 21:8-9 NLT

> Then we went on to Caesarea and stayed at the home of Philip the Evangelist, one of the seven men who had been chosen to distribute food.9 He had four unmarried daughters who had the gift of prophecy.

Yet it had to take Abagus to prophesy to Paul about his impending arrest

Acts 21:10 NLT

> During our stay of several days, a man named Agabus, who also had the gift of prophecy, arrived from Judea.11 When he visited us, he took Paul's belt and bound his own feet and hands with it. Then he said, "The Holy Spirit declares, 'So shall the owner of this belt be bound by the Jewish leaders in Jerusalem and turned over to the Romans.'"

Why was it Abagus who prophesied about Paul's impending arrest not the daughters of Philip?

Comment: We don't actually know that the daughters had nothing to say about it. The case might be that they prophesied about his arrest (which would be a good reason to mention them), but Luke chose to report only one prophecy to avoid repetition.

Comment: P.S. See my answer to the recent question about why the "Philip's daughters" story is included in Acts.

Comment: Because they were not the only prophets

Answer (score 1):

Again, we are not told so we cannot be certain.  However, here are some suggestions:

- the four daughters might have also prophesied but Luke was not inspired to record it
- Agabus prophesied because the Holy Spirit inspired him to do so, and not the four daughters on this occasion
- the four daughters were not present at the time but happened to be visiting elsewhere during Paul's visit

There could be a variety of other reasons as well.  The record we have in Acts is only a summary of a few highlights of what happened, and not a complete account.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is verse 10

> 10 While we were staying for many days, a prophet named Agabus **came down from Judea.**

Philip and his four daughters had the gift of prophesying, which should refer to their ability to preach the Gospel effectively. This made it reasonable for Agabus, who had come from Judea, to receive intelligence about the Jewish plot against Paul and hasten to Caesarea to save him.

Moreover, Agabus didn't just deliver a message; he also performed a sign that Luke recognized as coming from the Spirit.

> 11 And coming to us, **he took Paul's belt and bound his own feet and hands** and said, “Thus says the Holy Spirit, ‘This is how the Jews at Jerusalem will bind the man who owns this belt and deliver him into the hands of the Gentiles.’”

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little background to put the verse in context.

Paul was hurrying to go to Jerusalem to be there at Pentecost.

> Paul decided to sail past Ephesus, that there may not be to him a loss of time in Asia, for he was hurrying, if it were possible for him, to be at Jerusalem on the day of the Pentecost Act 20:16

Paul was bound, compelled by this desire to go to Jerusalem knowing that bonds and tribulations awaited him as a Holy Spirit had spoken to him of what was to happen.  Yet he knew this was the will of God for him.

> now, behold, I—bound in the Spirit—go on to Jerusalem, not knowing the things that will befall me in it, 23except that the Holy Spirit fully testifies in every city, saying that bonds and tribulations remain for me; 24but I make account of none of these, neither do I count my life precious to myself, so that I finish my course with joy, and the ministry that I received from the Lord Jesus, to fully testify [to] the good news of the grace of God.  Acts 20:22-24

Many of the disciples, also warned Paul, not to set foot in Jerusalem because through the spirit, they knew what was awaiting Paul in Jerusalem.

> 4And having found out the disciples, we tarried there seven days, and they said to Paul, through the Spirit, not to go up to Jerusalem; Acts 21:4

> We are not informed, whether the daughters of Philip added their warnings to the rest, but there seems to be no reason for mentioning their gift, unless they, to confirmed the word of the others. Concordant, literal commentary.

> Now there were four daughters of this man, virgins, prophesying.  Acts 22:9

Now Agabus , who was a certain prophet from Judea, came as well to prophesy to.
Probably the same prophet who came down to Antioch and prophesied the famine throughout the world.

> 27And in those days there came from Jerusalem prophets to Antioch, 28and one of them, by name Agabus, having stood up, did signify through the Spirit a great dearth is about to be throughout all the world — which also came to pass in the time of Claudius Caesar — Acts 11:27

When would assume Paul had met this prophet  before in Antioch,  when Agabus has prophesied about the famine.

This time does prophet is telling Paul directly what will happen to him in Jerusalem.

> a prophet named Agabus came down from Judea. 11Coming over to us, he took Paul’s belt, bound his own feet and hands, and said, “The Holy Spirit says: ‘In this way the Jews of Jerusalem will bind the owner of this belt and hand him over to the Gentiles.’ ” 12When we heard this, we and the people there pleaded with Paul not to go up to Jerusalem.
> Acts 21:11

> since he would not be persuaded, they all fell silent, remarking, "The Will of the Lord be done!"  Acts 21:14

OP's question,

> "Why was it Abagus who prophesied about Paul's impending arrest not the daughters of Philip?"

One can see from the previous scriptures that many had heard from the spirit of what was going to happen to Paul, even including himself.  Abagus is the last one who spoke this prophecy, he already had clout from his previous prophecy, and perhaps being from Judea, even gave him more influence.
Abagus was the last witness in the line of many and told exactly what would happened and of course it did.

So we see that nothing could detour Paul from going to Jerusalem and testifying to to the Lords cause as the Lord himself stood at his side.

> And on the following night, the LORD having stood by him, said, “Take courage, Paul, for as you fully testified [to] the things concerning Me at Jerusalem, so you must also testify at Rome.”  Acts 23:11